# Reverter um commit que ainda não recebeu push, e com varios comits esperando para receber push

Tags: git, commit

Em um dos commits que realizei eu inclui uma pasta com varios arquivos os quais totalizam uns 5gB aproximadamente, tentar realizar o push do mesmo commit ocorreu um erro (fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly), e o push não finalizou corretamente. Infelizmente eu não percebi que isso tinha acontecido, e continuei a trabalhar e a fazer novos commits, sempre que tentava realizar um push, o erro se repetia. Agora exitem varios commits que não receberam push, são 8 em total.

Este é o output do comando git status:
git status:

```
$ git status
On branch Optimizando
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/Optimizando' by 8 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   MAIN/DataResources/ExcelTables/Consola_00.xlsx
        modified:   MAIN/FUNCTIONS/Operar_Binary.py
        modified:   MAIN/FUNCTIONS/__pycache__/Operar_Binary.cpython-37.pyc
        modified:   MAIN/OPERATION_00.py

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .gitingnore
        ESTADISTICAS/
        MAIN/DataResources/ExcelTables/LOG.xlsx
        MAIN/F5.py
        MAIN/FUNCTIONS/copia.py
        MAIN/__pycache__/indices.cpython-37.pyc
        MAIN/test-2.py

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

o output do comando git cherry -v é o seguinte:

```
$ git cherry -v
+ d67a194ca3abc6847545488471a37a37bdfac060 Estadistica feu incorporado al servidor
+ 90021137be3752cf043fa9a67a9219121b5d9d95 error pabo
+ 6d65ef35c0568c5c261ce9b26d1fbe7526e02048 fix
+ c718a223615e84e2f2ef9172487bac7a58aeafce funcion gigante subdibidida
+ cd3e1e25a84da83e98e01c06df216fcc5e8f81d2 Conflictos
+ 20dae7b7f65762823cdc9f473e5bbe78d02479c7 Incorporacion Indices sintectico y eliminacion de Estadistica
+ 73d93be70f84c71bb98c8d519f7b742a12686472 Correcion en Menu desplegable de activos
+ a5e7f8d5d25f181f2d1ed39a76d509c272417933 Correcion en la seleccion de activo forex
```

o commit no qual foram incorporados os arquivos que estariam causando o erro é o de id: "d67a194ca3abc6847545488471a37a37bdfac060 Estadistica feu incorporado al servidor"

como poso reverter esse commit sem perder o trabalho que foi realizado apos eu ter adicionado os arquivos? Um detalhe importante, a pasta que continha os arquivos originalmente se chamava "Estatistica", no desespero eu tentei renomea-la para ESTATISTICAS porem isso isso não resolveu o problema.

Desde já muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer um

> git rebase -i d67a194ca^

e vai abrir uma tela onde você pode mudar a ordem dos commits, alterar a descrição, etc. É um comando muito poderoso. Pelo que entendi você quer descartar o commit d67a194, então edite a respectiva linha substituindo "pick" por "drop". Ou simplesmente remova a linha, que o commit vai ser desprezado.

É importante lembrar que isso vai "reescrever a história", ou seja, os commits que vieram depois do d67a194 vão ser refeitos como se aquele não tivesse existido. Se isso causar algum conflito, você pode ter de resolver manualmente.

Se você lê em inglês, pode dar uma olhada no meu texto https://epxx.co/artigos/gitfaces.html que descreve o uso do git rebase -i e da edição de conflitos durante o rebase interativo.